# Which is the best CMS to create a member based platform with individual dashboards?

Tags: web-development, cms, wordpress

I would like to create a website where people can do questionnaires and get a personal feedback. Can you recommend a CMS which can help me deal with that? 
In detail user should answer questions about their preferences. After that they have a dashboard where they can see points related to there answers and get a personal feedback and optimization recommendations. 
So the website needs a normal front-end with a dashboard for the users and a CMS Backend where the questions can be managed.

I found [this article](https://www.startups.com/community/questions/870/what-is-the-best-platform-to-create-a-member-based-cms-website-e-g-squarespace) but I am not sure if this really matches my problem

Comment: http://www.cmsmatrix.org/